# Difference between Managed and UnManaged Solution in CRM 5.0 (2011)?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am wondering what is the Difference between **Managed Solution** and **UnManaged Solution** in CRM 5.0 (2011)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Unmanaged solution:** Essentially the same as 4.0. As soon as someone imports an unmanaged solution into an organization, it becomes an integrated part of the organization and can only be removed by manually removing all parts of the solution. The components of it can be freely edited, changed, and removed.

**Managed solution:** Managed solutions can be locked down by the creators to not allow or allow editing of forms, adding new forms, changing display names, etc. A managed solution can be easily removed by just deleting the solution, and all components (that aren't needed for another solution) will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Unmanned Solution**:That solution we are edit update Unmanaged solutions are groups of unmanaged customizations. Any unmanaged customized solution component can be associated with any number of unmanaged solutions.
You create a managed solution by exporting an unmanaged solution and selecting to package it as a managed solution.

**Manged Solutions**:A managed solution is a completed solution that is intended to be distributed and installed.we cant modify and customizations that solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Also,
an UnManaged solution has no restrictions on what can be customized, and when you make changes to the system through an UnManaged solution the changes remain behind.
Managed solution all customizations are lost when it is deleted. So there is the potential for data loss in that event.